# How can I label a cluster that is formed in a 2D plot and associate it with the other similar 2D plots

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Suppose I have performed clustering on a data and identified few clusters along with a 2D plot. Let's say the identified clusters are at locations (2,5), (4,10), (6,15). Now I have repeated this process many times with other similar data.
I want to give an unique ID for each cluster that is formed in the first plot. Like 1,2,3 for clusters (2,5),(4,10),(6,15) respectively. Now, after clustering the other set of data, if the clusters are formed at same locations again, it should retain it's old ID, and a new ID should be allotted for a cluster at new location.

Any suggestions or leads for this implementation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a dictionary to store your cluster locations and cluster numbers. For example:

```
### Some populated dictionary last_clust -> {(2, 5): 1, (4, 10): 2, ...} 

curr_clust = {}
##Cluster generating code, generates clust_num and clust_location each loop
    clust_num = some_num
    clust_location = (x,y)
    if last_clust[clust_location] == clust_num:
        # clusters are same
        curr_clust[clust_location] = clust_num
    else:
        curr_clust[clust_location] = #some number above total number of clusters

# allows you to move to next cycle of clustering
last_clust = curr_clust
```